# sqlalchemy lef join with order

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make this SQL query in sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT t1.superior_id from "user" as t1 
LEFT JOIN "user" as t2 ON t1.superior_id = t2.id 
ORDER BY t2.first_name, t2.last_name;
```

Whole thing is - order users by the name of their superior.
But still getting many errors (depends on what i try at the moment). Totally don't know how to replicate this query in SA. Can someone help?

Comment: Look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html  for how to build the model. At the bottom is one little snippet `session.query(IPA).join(IPA.network)` which will give you some keywords to search the doc for showing how to query (see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#querying-2-0-style).   Also see https://github.com/cjbj/python-oracledb-demos-2022/blob/main/6_sqlalchemy_example.py

Answer (score 0):

I use Oracle_11g\instantclient_21_3 :
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/install-instant-client-using-zip.html

And for the query itself :

1. I would not use  ; at the end of the query
2. I would not use " " for the name of tables inside the query

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import pandas as pd

try:
    #im using Oracle_11g\instantclient_21_3 path as ORACLE_LIB_DIR  
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=ORACLE_LIB_DIR)
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)

try:    
    conn = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://" + USER + ":"+ PASS + "@" + DSN, max_identifier_length=30)
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)

 statement ="""
SELECT t1.superior_id from user as t1 
LEFT JOIN user as t2 ON t1.superior_id = t2.id 
ORDER BY t2.first_name, t2.last_name"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(statement, conn)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but i'm trying to make this query with sqlalchemy ORM, of course i know that i can paste raw sql query, but it not the problem :)